# Redirecting traffic to different folders within a server

Tags: javascript, html

I built an education platform and stored all the files in a folder on the server called 2016. I use an index.html file to redirect traffic to the 2016 folder. I just updated all the files and decided to put them in a 2018 folder. When i updated the index.html file to redirect to the 2018 it keeps going to the 2016 folder. On Firefox the redirect works but chrome is being stubborn. What is happening?

here is the code in the index.html file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title>
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        window.location.href = "2018/index.html";
    </script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Could you please paste the code? 
TIP: If you're changing it inside a JavaScript file and you can't see your changes, just check if you isn't using a copy inside the browser cache.

Comment: here is the code in the index.html file:

Comment: <!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <title>Page Title</title> 
</head>

<body>

    <script>
        window.location.href = "2018/index.html";
    </script>

</body>
</html>

Comment: Don't use comments for code.

Answer (score 0):

Better to not use javascript for redirecting, use the plain html `<meta>` tag instead.

This is much better for search engines robots, and you are then sure that it will works everywhere including internet explorer and oldies:

```
// Redirect to http://example.com/ after 5 seconds:

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://example.com/">

// Redirect to http://example.com/ immediately:

<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; url=http://example.com/">
```

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Meta_refresh